# ffmpeg command to is throwing error

Tags: ffmpeg

I am new to ffmpeg usage.
I am trying to merge two video file.
The below bullets will provide you more details about it.
 1. I-ball usb camera 
 2.  Screen capture utility named UScreenCapture.

The below command i am using on DOS.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow  -i video="iBall Face2Face Webcam C12.0" -f dshow -i video="UScreenCapture"  -r 25 -vcodec mpeg4 -q 12 -f mpegts test.ts
```

This command captures only from `Uscreencapture` source.

while grabbing frames from Camera it is giving me an error saying that 
real-time buffer 90% full! frame dropped!
real-time buffer 121% full! frame dropped!

Can any one provide me the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need the ffmpeg -map function

"Designate one or more input streams as a source for the output file"

[FFMPEG "-map" Documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options)